# Camera on the top of GoogleMaps DJI Mobile SDK Android

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I am developing an application that sends specific commands to a DJI Phantom 3 Advanced. I am trying to have Google Maps on the main screen and have a small square of the camera view on the bottom left of the screen. However, I can't manage to see the camera on this square. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I created the same thing is to have the map and the video stream implemented in separate Fragments.  The map fragment is match_parent and the video fragment is a percentage of the screen and anchored in lower-right.

Hope this helps; it should be fairly straight forward once you have the fragment working.

Comment: There isn't much to it but this is what I do...

In layout: